# Can I use "instead" without "of"?

Tags: grammar

Grammarly says no, but I don't trust Grammarly. I was trying to use it in a paragraph for Fahrenheit 451, saying

> Nothing makes you think for yourself, instead coaxing you into forgetting about the real issue.

Wouldn't this work when you consider the definition of 'stead', since I'm trying to say that 'nothing' is making you forget instead of making you think? I suppose it's just backwards, but it seems correct.

Comment: Welcome! Could you quote, or at least link to, the Grammarly advice you mention?

Comment: With a more tractable example: 'The bus didn't take the correct turn for the town centre, taking us to the harbour instead' = 'The bus didn't take the correct turn for the town centre, instead taking us to the harbour.'

Comment: Hmmm. *Instead of* and *instead* are used with completely opposite meanings. *Instead of* takes as its complement the thing that that was replaced or the event that did not happen: "Instead of going to the cinema, I did my homework". In stark contrast *instead* used on its own is used to mark the alternative replacement or the thing that **did** happen: "I didn't go to the cinema but did my homework instead" or "I didn't do to the cinema. Instead, I did my homework".

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. 1a Instead of going to the cinema, I did my homework. 1b I did my homework instead of going to the cinema. 1c I did my homework instead. 2a Before going to the cinema, I did my homework. 2b I did my homework before going to the cinema. 2c I did my homework before. I see no stark contrast.

Answer (score 3):

There's no reason "instead" always has to be accompanied by "of," but you'd have to construct the sentence differently; when you remove "of," the "instead" points to something different. Let's take a simpler sentence:

> I ran away instead of talking to you.

You *did* run away, and *didn't* talk. The complement to "instead of" is "talking." But you could also say:

> I didn't talk to you, instead running away.

Now "instead" modifies "running"; "instead" has been pulled into the service of the *positive* statement rather than the negative one. This sentence works only because I negated "talk."

Your example sentence is hampered by the fact that the subject is "nothing." It isn't a negation; the concept of "nothing" does in fact do something ("makes you think"). So we run into a problem when we look for a subject for the second half of the sentence: "Nothing" "coaxes you into forgetting"? Oh dear.

The sentence would work if you recast it with a positive subject but with "think" negated:

> [Bradbury's dystopian government] never makes you think for yourself, instead coaxing you into...

Comment: Hmmm. *Instead of* and *instead* are used with completely opposite meanings. *Instead of* takes as its complement the thing that that was replaced or the event that did not happen: "Instead of going to the cinema, I did my homework". In stark contrast *instead* used on its own is used to mark the alternative replacement or the thing that **did** happen: "I didn't go to the cinema but did my homework instead" or "I didn't do to the cinema. Instead, I did my homework".

Comment: PS, I deleted a comment I wrote earlier, because I was under the mistaken impression that the original sentence was written *by* Bradbury, and not about him! :-)

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Good point, I should edit to highlight that the construction without "of" switches the complement.

Comment: Good edit, but one niggle. *Instead* on its own doesn't have a complement, but is a modifier of the clause it precedes or appears in. (It's the fact that that clause looks like a complement when it follows *instead* that causes the problem - and that's what happens in the OP's sentence!)